# Conditional probability and distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let Y ∼ Exp(1/5). Find P(Y ≤ 18|Y > 13).

Could anyone give me any hints?

Comment: Use the defining formula $\Pr(A|B)=\frac{A\cap B}{\Pr(B)}$. Here $B$ is $Y\gt 13$. You can calculate $\Pr(Y\gt 13)$ using integration. And $A\cap B$ is $13\lt Y\le 18$. The probability is $\Pr(Y\le 18)-\Pr(Y\le 13)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: you know that $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\wedge B)}{P(B)}.$$

What are $A$ and $B$ in your case? What is $A$ and $B$ (written as $A\wedge B$)? Edit your answer with the answers to these questions and I will help some more.

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate the exponential distribution into this

Comment: @Eric Forget about the exponential distribution for a second. Can you tell me what $A$ is in your case? How can you use the conditional probability formula?